# LoRa RSSI value is not accurate

Tags: radio, lora

I want to use LoRa (SX1280) to locate devices by RSSI and TDOA.

I put two LoRa devices on the table (within one meter), one for TX one for RX, and the RSSI values change a lot.

Then I power off the TX device, the RSSI values of RX device also changes a lot.

I don't know how the chip calculates the value, but I only want to get the received packet RSSI value.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Results of any such scheme are likely to be marginal and probably due to overload meaningless until you get to a larger distance.  If you wish to do this yourself, you'd need to pay attention to the distinction between monitoring the instantaneous RSSI and averaging, vs. the packet RSSI captured at the sync word.  If you want to use the alleged support for an explicit ranging scheme, you should see if you can find whatever app note and/or example code Semtech has for that.

Comment: TDOA requries multiple *gateways* with such support, not simply node chips.

Comment: LoRa works on public sub-GHz frequencies. RSSI is typically just a measurement of raw signal strength by any device on the same frequency. So it might very well be that some other equipment is already using that frequency.

Comment: And then obviously, it might not be able to measure very low powers accurately. Suppose the scale goes down to some -60dBm. The lower background noice will then always cause values to flicker. RSSI in general is rarely ever steady unless you have a strong signal on carrier.